# Problem about linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose we have two $n \times n$ square matrices *A* and *B* such that $AB=BA$. It is known that *A*, *B* and *AB* all have *n* distinct eigenvectors that is a basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$. Can we then show that there is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that comprises entirely of vectors that are eigenvectors of both *A* and *B*?

---

I have no idea on solving this problem. Any form of help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the notation ^n ?

Comment: Do you mean $\Bbb R^{n}$ when you say ^n?

Comment: @user46944 How can I type that symbol?

Comment: @Linear: The LaTeX code for $\mathbb{R}^n$ is \mathbb{R}^n. Enclose that in dollar signs so that this site knows to parse it as LaTeX (specifically an implementation thereof known as MathJax), and voila.

Comment: can you give us the reference of what you say in the text "it is  known ...."

Comment: certainly it is your hypotheses,  in this case, I apologize, I have difficulty with the English language

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be a matrix of an endomorphism $f$  of $E$. then if $F_1$
and $F_2$ are two supplementary sub-space in $E$ (that is
$E=F_1\oplus F_2$),  and are stable under $f$ then by a choice of
bases in $F_1$ and in $F_2$, the  matrix  of $f$ in the base
obtened of $E$ (meeting of two preceding bases) is a diagonal
block matrix  with two block, and $f$ is diagonalized  iff the
restriction of $f$ to each $F_i$ is diagonalized.

Let  $A$ and $B$ two  diagonalizable matrix such that $AB = BA$,
and $E =\oplus_{\lambda\in spect(A)} E_\lambda$ where $E_\lambda$
is the eigenvector space of $A$ relatively to eigenvalue
$\lambda$. so  for each $\lambda\in spect(A)$, if $v\in E_\lambda$
then $AB(v)=B(A(v))=B(\lambda v)=\lambda B(v)$ this means that
each $E_\lambda $ is stable by $B$ so we can diagonalize the
restriction of $B$ to each $E_\lambda$, so we get base of $E$
constituted by eigenvectors of both $A$ and $B$.